# Can't understand small part of a C program involving pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory

```
int x = 5;
int y = 6;
int *p = &x;
*p = x + y;
p = &y;
*p = x + y;
printf("%d,%d", x, y);
```

I can understand the first 3 lines. I know that `int *p = &x;` means that the pointer `p` is pointing at the memory address of `x`. But I can't understand the next 4 lines of the code. The output for this code is:

```
 11,17
```

But I unable to understand how? Can someone explain it to me.

Comment: Just replace *p with x or y as appropriate in the code and then it becomes obvious.

Comment: _"I know that `int *p = &x;` means the pointer `p` is pointing at the memory address of `x`"_ That's funny, because it's not! It's pointing at `x`.

Comment: It seems to be Binky's time again: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/ http://www.cs.stanford.edu/cslibrary/PointerFunCBig.avi

Answer (score 4):

> A pointer is a variable whose value is the address of another variable, i.e., direct address of the memory location.

When you are assigning like this,

```
 int *p=&x;// It will point to the address of x variable.
```

Any change done in the `*p`, It will affect the memory. So while you are accessing that with the `x` it have the value.

```
 *p=x+y; // It's equivalent x=x+y;
```

Then  `y` also like this.

Now `x` have the value `11`.  `p=&y;`

```
  *p=x+y;// It's equivalent to y=x+y;
```

so now x have the value `11` and y value `5`. So the result is `17`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's analyze the code line by line, shall we?

Before going into the answer, a small info, `*` is called the *indirection* or *dereference* operator, which is used to access the *value at a memory address*.

So, per your code:

- `*p = x + y;`  add `x` and `y` and store the value at the *memory location pointed by `p`* <sup>[i.e. the address of `x`].</sup>. So, this way, the actual value of `x` is getting modified. now, `x` holds `x+y` or `5+6` or `11`.
- `p = &y;` same logic as `int *p = &x;`
- `*p = x + y;` same logic as the first point. remember, `x` value got modified in the first occasion, so the latest `x` value will be considered. So, modified `y` will be `11 + 6` or `17`.
- `printf("%d,%d", x, y);` Now don't tell me you did not understand this line. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
      *p = x + y;
```

So now p will point the address of x, and (*p) will point the value stored in the x. so your changing the value of x , in its memory location.

```
       p = &y;
```

Now your assigning the address of y to p.

```
       *p = x + y;
```

Now you change the value of y using its memory address.

Answer (score 0):

In fact this code snippet

```
int x = 5;
int y = 6;
int *p = &x;
*p = x + y;
p = &y;
*p = x + y;
printf("%d,%d", x, y);
```

you may rewrite the following way without using pointers that it would be more clear

```
int x = 5;
int y = 6;
x = x + y;
y = x + y;
printf("%d,%d", x, y);
```

So at first `x` is set to the sum of `x + y` and will be equal to `11` and then `y` is set to the sum of updated `x` (that now is equal to 11) and `y` and will be equal to `17`.

The only difference that instead of using directly `x` and `y` the first code snippet uses pointers.

Thus

statement 
    x = x + y;
is replaced with combination of these two statements

```
int *p = &x;
*p = x + y;
```

and statement

```
y = x + y;
```

is replaced with combination of these two statements

```
p = &y;
*p = x + y;
```

That is at first pointer p is assigned the address of x

```
int *p = &x;
```

and the object (that is x) is assigned the sum of x + y

```
*p = x + y;
```

The same is repeated for varaiable y and pointer p.

Answer (score 0):

```
*p = x + y
```

Dereference pointer p, assign value of `x + y` to the memory that p is pointing to. Equivalent to `x = x + y`. 
x is equal to `x + y` now, which is `5 + 6 = 11`.

`p = &y`

Assign the the address of y to pointer p. Pointer p points to memory of y in other word.

`*p = x +y`

Dereference pointer p, assign value of `x + y` to the memory that p is pointing to.   Equivalent to  `y = x + y`. y is equal to x + y now, which is `11 + 6 = 17`.

At the end, `x = 11`, `y = 17`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To better understand pointers and related ampersand and asterisk symbols i propose to this basic statements:
lets assume:

```
int * p;
int x;
```

1) Pointer is an address. That means that in  p is an address in memory where integer value is stored 
2) when *p is used the asterisk symbol can be "translated" as "value at the address"; This means that when we used *p we want take a value that resides in address p; 
3) when &x is used the ampersand symbol can be "translated" as "address of"; This means that we want to take address of x;

thus operations: 
0) p = x; would not be correct;
1) *p = x; is correct (if p is a valid address) and value at address p is now same as value x;
2) p = &x; is correct, and *p == x; in this case also you need to understand, that p and &x is the same address. so if you change either *p or x, the other one will have same value as well.